# CefSharp - Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I've installed **CefSharp.OffScreen (121.3.70)** on my **.NET Framework 4.7.2** API project, to take screenshots of certain webpages.

After installed, I saw that it was needed to specify an compiler target, I specified the **compiler target to x64**.

When I run the project, this error pops up:
Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies

After some researched I've already tried the following:

- Ensure Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages are installed
- Added `<CefSharpBuildAction>Content</CefSharpBuildAction>` tag to the project (.vbproj)
- Repaired my Visual Studio in case of some dependency breaking or missing

The CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core is moved to the bin/Debug folder as expected, but was still not found.

I've already tested this library in an .NET Core project, of which I didn't found any problems.

Comment: What's an API project exactly? CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL shouldn't be referenced directly in your project. Does the problem reproduce with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: It is an solution with an API project built on MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb. I'm trying to use the Cefsharp in an another project of this solution. No, the problem does not reproduce with the minimal example. Thanks

Comment: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL is not being referenced directly, I've just installed the CefSharp.OffScreen package.

Comment: https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp?tab=readme-ov-file#puppeteer-sharp is an alternative option that is worth investigating.